# Yii2:redirect to specific action from submit button

Tags: php, yii2

I am not able to redirect a custom form to specific action.

What I am trying is

```
<?= Html::submitButton( 'delete-selected' ,['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

here `delete-selected` is my custom action in controller `appointment`.

I have also tried like this:

```
public function actionDeleteForm()
    {
        return $this->render('delete');
        return $this->redirect(['delete-selected']);
    }

public function actionDeleteSelected()
{
    Appointment::deleteAll(['doctor_name' =>4]);
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

What I am trying to do is actually delete some records using the form. The form name is `delete` having a select drop-down field.

I want to post the data to action `deleteselected` and use the $_POST variable in the delete query.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any submit button that you put on your form will submit to the url specified in the action parameter of the form. If you haven't specified one, then Yii will use the current controller/action of the form. If you want to override this behavior, then you will need to specify an action for the form. e.g.

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => 'appointment/delete-selected'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

in actionDeleteForm you have

```
return $this->render('delete');
```

before

```
return $this->redirect(['delete-selected'])
```

this  second instruction will never be executed because you have already made a return to the function and then control has already been returned to the caller

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat a note for [Joe Miller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29225116/2947502). If you are supposed to override the form's action with an action of a controller, make sure you make the value of 'action' as an array:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
'action' => ['appointment/delete-selected']
]);
```

It will treat the action as a route to action `delete-selected` in controller `appointment`.

Comment: Not strictly true. The `action` parameter will accept either a string or an array, see here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$action-detail. The only benefit to passing an array is if you want to pass additional parameters to the action.